# parsing a page that needs user login using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, curl, authentication

I was trying to login to a page using Curl of php.. & then parse the data after login.. I posted the values of all the variables using Curl.. bt amnt able to login to the page.. pls help..

here's my code:

```
<?php
$fields_string=array();
$url = '`http://data.bsnl.in/wps/portal/!ut/p/c5/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hnd0cPE3!MfAwMLFzcLAyMnUzPPQAMXAwNfM_1wkA6zeAMcwNFA388jPzdVP1I_yhynOa4G-iH6kU76Bdl55QaOiooAzstUAA!!/dl3/d3/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/`';

$fields = array(
            "userID"=>"xxxxxxxx",
    "password"=>"xxxxxxx"
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
$fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: why do you have quotes in your URL?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$fields = array(
    "userID"   => "xxxxxxxx",
    "password" => "xxxxxxxx"
);
```

try

```
$fields = array(
    "wps.portlets.userid" => "xxxxxxxx",
    "password"            => "xxxxxxxx"
);
```